# Deploy code using GIT - checkout vs reset --hard?

Tags: git

I need to make sure that one of my python deploy location on the server is always in sync with a remote branch and remove any changes on the server. What is the difference between Option 1 and Option 2? Which one is preferred? I intend to run this on a timely manner to ensure server code is in sync with remote.

Option 1:

```
git clean -f -x
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Option 2:

```
git clean -f -x
git fetch --all
git checkout --force origin/master
```

Comment: I'd personally do a git pull

Comment: I want to ignore any commits that anyone might have made on the server (even though that is unlikely)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the difference properly, let's start with these definitions:

- A Git repository contains *commits*, which are snapshots of some tree-of-files-in-directories (a *tree*) with associated metadata, typically including one parent commit (but any number of parent commit IDs are allowed).  These commits are identified by big ugly hash IDs, `deadc0defeedbeefac0ffee...` and so on.  Because these big ugly hash IDs are big, ugly, and seemingly-random, we use names—branch and tag names, mainly—to keep track of them.

  Files stored in the repository have a form useful only to Git itself.  Normal commands cannot read them.  (Nothing but Git can *write* these stored objects, and they have a write-once form: once written, they can never be changed.  This is true of all four kinds of Git objects, but *not* of branch names, which are *supposed* to change: the hash ID stored under a branch name changes every time you add a new commit to the branch.)
- Every repository also has an *index*.  The index—note that there is one special, distinguished "the" index—is where you build the *next* commit you intend to make.  It starts out matching some existing commit.  The index has several roles, including making Git go fast (its *cache* role), and handling merges and arranging for the next commit (its *staging area* role).  But it starts out matching some existing commit.

  The index is, essentially, a flattened tree, so it is like the contents of a commit in that particular way.  As with internal Git objects, it is in a form useful only to Git.
- Most repositories also have a (single, distinguished) *work tree*, which is where you do your work on your files.  Like the index, the tree starts out matching some commit.  Because these are ordinary files the rest of the computer can deal with, though, they can be written-to as well as read, or you can add new files or remove files.

  If you change a file in the work-tree, and want to commit the new version, you must copy the file from the work-tree into the index.  This is what `git add` does: it copies a file into the index, either replacing the existing one—if the file's path-name was in there before—or storing an entirely new one (if the path-name is new).

  Likewise, to remove a file from the index, you must run `git rm`.  By default this removes the file from *both* the index *and* the work-tree (but you can tell it to leave the work-tree version alone).
- A repository always<sup>1</sup> has one *current commit*.  This is called the HEAD commit.  The way `.git/HEAD` (it's an ordinary file, in the `.git` directory) really works is that it normally just contains the *current branch name*.  The actual commit ID is stored under the branch name.  However, Git has what is called "detached HEAD" mode, where `HEAD` contains a hash ID instead.  This all matters in a moment for both `git checkout` and `git reset`.

So, there is a *current commit*, usually from a *current branch name*, plus the fact that a branch name is really just a way to look up the name-to-ID mapping to find the commit.  We call that `HEAD`, which is short for: "Hey, Git, go read `.git/HEAD`, find the current branch name, and use that to find the current commit.  Or, if I'm in detached HEAD mode, read `.git/HEAD` as before, but see that it has a hash ID instead, and then *that*'s the current commit."

Now, the two different commands you are looking at here are `git reset` and `git checkout`.  These have very different *goals*:

- `git reset` is (mostly<sup>2</sup>) about changing the *current branch name's name-to-ID mapping* in some way, with the option of also changing the index too, or even changing all three: the current commit, the index, *and* the work-tree.
- `git checkout` is (mostly) about changing *which branch is the current branch*, by writing a new branch name into HEAD, or by "detaching" HEAD: writing a commit hash ID into HEAD.  In the process, `git checkout` *will* change both the index and the work-tree.

Here is where things get a bit complicated. :-) Since you are using `--hard`, `git reset` *will* update the index and work-tree.  So now it sounds like it is a lot more like `git checkout`, and in some ways it is.  But there are a couple of critical differences:

1. Using `git reset` *changes which commit the current branch points-to.*  Using `git checkout` changes *which commit is current.*

   Remember, we said above that names like `master` and `develop` are how we get Git to remember big ugly hash IDs.  The effect is that these names act like labels, pasted onto, or pointing to, specific commits.  The `git reset` command lets you *move* the label: to change where it points; to peel it off one specific commit and paste it onto another.  By contrast, `git checkout` *does not* move labels.  Instead, it changes *which branch name* is stored in `.git/HEAD`.  You `git checkout master` to switch to branch `master`, and then `git checkout develop` to switch to branch `develop`.  The labels stay where they are, but Git changes the *name* stored in `.git/HEAD`.

   All of this applies in the *normal* case, when you are "on a branch".  If you are in the "detached HEAD" case, `git reset` still moves your detached HEAD from one commit to another—but since there's no branch *name* involved, this does not change any existing branch names.  Likewise, if you `git checkout` something that is not a branch name, `git checkout` "detaches your HEAD" by writing the raw commit ID into `.git/HEAD`.

   Note that `git reset` never detaches HEAD and never re-attaches HEAD.  That's something that `git checkout` does.  Meanwhile, `git checkout` never changes any branch labels, but `git reset` does.
2. The `git checkout` command *tries to be non-destructive* (in this mode anyway; see footnote 2 again).  The `git reset` command *happily destroys unsaved work*.

   In practice, what this means is that if you have made changes to the index and/or work-tree, `git checkout` won't overwrite them.  This gets particularly complicated, because it *will* switch branches or commits, if it can.  It does so by leaving the unsaved work in place, in the index and/or work-tree, if it can.  If it can't, it simply errors out.

   By contrast, `git reset --hard` will throw away these unsaved changes: `--hard` means overwrite both index and work-tree.

In a comment, you added:

> I want to ignore any commits that anyone might have made on the server (even though that is unlikely)

but "ignore" is different from "discard", and none of this addresses uncommitted changes made to the index and/or work-tree.

Normally, the right thing to do with a centralized server like this is to set one up that *has no work-tree*, i.e., is a `--bare` repository.  A repository that has no work-tree can have no work being done in it.  There is nothing to maybe-save, maybe-ignore, or maybe-discard in the first place.  If you use this method, all these distinctions fall away.  That's your best bet.

Even if you cannot or will not use a `--bare` repository, let's look at the remaining items.  Besides all of the above considerations, remember that a centralized repository—one to which someone `git push`es *new* commits in the first place—still has a current (HEAD) commit, which—if it is not detached—names a current branch.  It also still has an index, and if not bare, a work-tree.  Git will normally refuse a push to the current branch of a work-tree: see `receive.denyCurrentBranch` in [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).  Since a bare repository has no work-tree, this particular Git problem also vanishes for bare repositories.

(Your description, though, sounds like you have this set up not as a central server to which others push directly, but rather as a client of yet another server, where you use `git fetch` on the client.  If that's the case, several items below become non-issues.)

So, let's say you have a non-bare repository, with a work-tree.  To allow pushes to succeed, you will probably need to use a detached HEAD, otherwise Git will refuse pushes to the current branch.  (Newer Gits have the ability to accept them, but you must use it very carefully; see the linked documentation for details.)  A detached HEAD will give you a current commit without a current branch, and will make `git reset` and `git checkout` closer cousins than if you were on a branch.

(It also defeats a feature that clients see when they clone the central repository: clients will check out whichever branch is current on the server, i.e., the client asks the server "what's your HEAD branch?" and checks that out automatically.  This feature has somewhat dubious value, so you may not miss it, but it's worth noting.)

If you are using this detached HEAD, then, the primary difference between `git reset --hard origin/master` and `git checkout origin/master` is what happens to uncommitted index and/or work-tree modifications.  With `git reset --hard`, they will be wiped out, with no warning.  Anyone actively working on the server will be [SOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SOL).  The index and work-tree will be re-set to match the new commit.

If you are *not* using a detached HEAD, `git reset --hard origin/master` will write the commit ID for `origin/master` into the current branch name.  As before, `git reset` will update the index and work-tree as well.  This not only wipes out active work, it also *throws away* commits made on the current branch, by peeling the branch label off the old commit and pasting it onto the new one.

With `git checkout`, well, this is also a bit complicated.  Since `origin/master` is a so-called *remote-tracking branch*, checking out this name gives you a detached HEAD, with the commit hash stored directly in `.git/HEAD`.  This is true regardless of whether HEAD was attached or detached before.  So `HEAD` now *is* detached, provided that the checkout succeeds.  If there are no uncommitted changes in the index and work-tree, the checkout should<sup>3</sup> succeed.  If there *are* uncommitted changes, the checkout will carry them to the new detached HEAD if possible, or fail if switching to that commit cannot be done without wiping out the uncommitted work.

Hence, those are your options, if you choose to proceed along this path.  Since Git is a large tool-set, rather than a single canned solution, you can pick some *other* path(s) if those are more suitable.

(Note that `git clean -f -x` will remove untracked and ignored files, i.e., things that are not in the index.  Without `-d`, however, it will not remove untracked directories.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There is an exception to this "always a current commit" rule, used mainly for the case of a new, empty repository, when there are no commits at all.  You won't encounter this exception unless you are working in an empty repository, or use `git checkout --orphan` to create a new but *unborn branch*, as Git calls it.

<sup>2</sup>Both `git reset` and `git checkout` have additional usages that deviate, anywhere from a little bit to a lot, from their main function.  I am describing only their main function here.

<sup>3</sup>A `git checkout` can still fail due to, e.g., running out of disk space.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear explanation! I think I would need git reset --hard since I want to throw away any changes done on the "server".

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: replaces all of your work on master branch with what was fetched

Option 2: just switches you to the master branch

Comment: Since it is git checkout origin/master, is it not equivalent to Option 1 in terms of the contents of workspace ?

Comment: I still don't believe it will permanently erase your current work. Option 2, is the safer option.