# Git Deploy Web Hook command - Don't quite understand it.

Tags: git, deployment

I've just been deploying to my server using Web Hooks for the first time.
However, I'm struggling to understand the git command, especially checkout being at the end of the command?

This is the command I'm using:

`git --work-tree=/location/ --git-dir=/source.git/ checkout -f`

I'm unsure what the checkout is doing at the end? If anyone could explain, it would help as it's baffling my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Git as a deployment tool, which is a bit like using a wrench as a hammer: it works, but there are good reasons not to do that.

Running:

```
git --work-tree=/location/ --git-dir=/source.git/ checkout -f
```

is very similar to running:

```
git checkout -f
```

I assume here that you are already used to using `git checkout` with a *branch name* to check out a particular branch.  If you consult [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html), you'll see that you can also run `git checkout` *without* a branch name:

> You could omit *branch*;, in which case the command degenerates to "check out the current branch", which is a glorified no-op with rather expensive side-effects to show only the tracking information, if exists, for the current branch.

That is, if this particular repository is currently on branch `master`, running `git checkout` means `git checkout master`, which it's already on.  So now let's pay attention to the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options—which means looking at [the front-end `git` command documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html).  The most important part is actually the `--work-tree` option, because the `--git-dir` parameter is already set by the fact that this is operating as a Git hook (Git hooks are run with `$GIT_DIR` pre-set):

> `--work-tree=path`
>
>   Set the path to the working tree. ...

Essentially, this tells Git: *don't look for the work-tree in the usual place, wherever that is, look over in this other `path` location*.  In a "bare" Git repository (on a web server), typically the Git repository itself is set up to have *no* work-tree at all.  You must therefore use `--work-tree` (or anything equivalent) to force Git to assume that this other directory, such as `/location/`, contains the checked-out repository.

The `checkout` verb then tells Git to take whatever is in the current work-tree (over in this other location) and re-check-out the current branch, whatever the current branch is (probably `master`).  The `-f` option is an option to `git checkout` and it stands for *force*, meaning: *Even if this checkout will clobber some work-in-progress, do it anyway.*  Normally `git checkout` is careful not to overwrite work-in-progress.

Of course, on your web server, there should be no work-in-progress: the files in the deployment location probably *should* match what Git thinks they are.  So the `-f` *should* generally be unnecessary.  However, this whole idea of *what Git thinks is in the work-tree* is itself a problem.  Git *keeps track* of the work-tree through what Git calls its *index*.  If you push the deployment idea too hard, using Git itself as the deployment tool, you will find that Git's keeping-track breaks the deployment.  This is *why* it's like using a wrench as a hammer: it works if you apply it gently enough, or know what you are doing and are careful, but if you are doing a lot of hammering, the wrench may break.

For a pro-Git-as-deployment-tool article that covers some of both arguments, see https://www.freelock.com/blog/john-locke/2015-06/case-git-deployment-tool.  See also [Deploy code using GIT - checkout vs reset --hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42569205/1256452) and [git post-receive hook doesn't seem to process other branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43025000/1256452) as well.